# Multiple imputation with mice in R: How can I avoid implausible variable combinations and specify the range and unrated values of variables?

Tags: r, r-mice

I set up a multiple imputation model in mice, including modification of the method and predictor matrix. Now, I would like to specify more details for which I could not yet find helpful information. I have a dataset with four measurement times and use pmm for the following variables. All items/scale means (but not demographic variables) were collected at all measurement times. The dataset is in wide format.

1. Inconsistencies in variable combinations: The dataset includes the variables age and tenure. I would also like to specify that tenure must be <= (age − 21). I think it could be done with an artificial variable, but how can I implement it? Alternatively, is there an even better approach?
2. Some scale means can range between 1 and 5; however, the observed values do not cover the full range (e.g., they start with 2 instead). How can I specify that the values can range from 1 to 5?
3. Discrete variables: I used Likert scales ranging from 1 to 5. For some items, the participants did not rate certain values (e.g., 1). How can I achieve that these unrated values can also be imputed?

Here is a snippet of the relevant part of my code, only using the EXH variables:

```
ini <- mice(dataset, maxit = 0)
meth <- ini$method
pred <- ini$predictorMatrix

#To impute means and item values correctly: passive imputation of means EXH
meth["EXH_t1mean"] <- "~I((EXH1_t1+ EXH2_t1+ EXH3_t1+ EXH4_t1+ EXH5_t1+ EXH6_t1+ EXH7_t1+ EXH8_t1)/8)"
meth["EXH_t2mean"] <- "~I((EXH1_t2+ EXH2_t2+ EXH3_t2+ EXH4_t2+ EXH5_t2+ EXH6_t2+ EXH7_t2+ EXH8_t2)/8)"
meth["EXH_t3mean"] <- "~I((EXH1_t3+ EXH2_t3+ EXH3_t3+ EXH4_t3+ EXH5_t3+ EXH6_t3+ EXH7_t3+ EXH8_t3)/8)"
meth["EXH_t4mean"] <- "~I((EXH1_t4+ EXH2_t4+ EXH3_t4+ EXH4_t4+ EXH5_t4+ EXH6_t4+ EXH7_t4+ EXH8_t4)/8)"

#to avoid feedback loops, means as predictors for items removed
pred[c("EXH1_t1", "EXH2_t1", "EXH3_t1", "EXH4_t1", "EXH5_t1", "EXH6_t1", "EXH7_t1", "EXH8_t1"), "EXH_t1mean"] <- 0
pred[c("EXH1_t2", "EXH2_t2", "EXH3_t2", "EXH4_t2", "EXH5_t2", "EXH6_t2", "EXH7_t2", "EXH8_t2"), "EXH_t2mean"] <- 0
pred[c("EXH1_t3", "EXH2_t3", "EXH3_t3", "EXH4_t3", "EXH5_t3", "EXH6_t3", "EXH7_t3", "EXH8_t3"), "EXH_t3mean"] <- 0
pred[c("EXH1_t4", "EXH2_t4", "EXH3_t4", "EXH4_t4", "EXH5_t4", "EXH6_t4", "EXH7_t4", "EXH8_t4"), "EXH_t4mean"] <- 0

#as I have many variables, I use the technique described by van Buuren ([Chapter 6.4.5][1]), using only the scale means to predict other variables
pred[, c("EXH1_t1", "EXH2_t1", "EXH3_t1", "EXH4_t1", "EXH5_t1", "EXH6_t1", "EXH7_t1", "EXH8_t1",
        "EXH1_t2", "EXH2_t2", "EXH3_t2", "EXH4_t2", "EXH5_t2", "EXH6_t2", "EXH7_t2", "EXH8_t2",
        "EXH1_t3", "EXH2_t3", "EXH3_t3", "EXH4_t3", "EXH5_t3", "EXH6_t3", "EXH7_t3", "EXH8_t3",
        "EXH1_t4", "EXH2_t4", "EXH3_t4", "EXH4_t4", "EXH5_t4", "EXH6_t4", "EXH7_t4", "EXH8_t4")] <- 0

imp <- mice(dataset, m = 10, maxit = 10, meth = meth, pred = pred, seed = 1234, print = FALSE)
```

For this section, only Questions 1 and 3 are relevant. However, there are also other variables that are only mean values; this is why I also asked Question 2.

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can answer the question more easily? Thank you!